# How do I log messages / break execution for alloc, retain, release and dealloc of CFType objects?

Tags: xcode, macos, ios, core-foundation, dtrace

I want to be able to log messages (and preferably break to the debugger) each time a specific `CFType` object (for my current purposes, a `CGPDFDocument`) is allocated, retained, released or deallocated.

Because there isn't a `Create...()` method for `CGPDFDocument` which takes a `CFAllocatorRef`, I'm trying to change the default allocator temporarily like this:

```
void MyPDFDocumentCreate()
{
    // ...

    CFAllocatorRef defaultAllocator = CFAllocatorGetDefault();
    CFAllocatorSetDefault(MyLogAllocator());

    CGPDFDocumentRef documentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

    CFAllocatorSetDefault(defaultAllocator);

    // ...
}
```

where `MyLogAllocator()` is defined as follows:

```
static void *(*DefaultAllocate)(CFIndex size, CFOptionFlags hint, void *info);
static const void *(*DefaultRetain)(const void *info);
static void (*DefaultRelease)(const void *info);

void *LogAllocate(CFIndex size, CFOptionFlags hint, void *info)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "LogAllocate %p", info);
    if (DefaultAllocate)
        return DefaultAllocate(size, hint, info);
    else
        return NULL;
}

const void *LogRetain(const void *info)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "LogRetain");
    if (DefaultRetain)
        return DefaultRetain(info);
    else
        return info;
}

void LogRelease(const void *info)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "LogRelease");
    if (DefaultRelease)
        DefaultRelease(info);
}

static CFAllocatorRef MyLogAllocator()
{
    static CFAllocatorRef theLogAllocator = NULL;

    if (!theLogAllocator)
    {
        CFAllocatorContext context;
        CFAllocatorRef defaultAllocator = CFAllocatorGetDefault();
        CFAllocatorGetContext(defaultAllocator, &context);

        DefaultAllocate = context.allocate;
        DefaultRetain = context.retain;
        DefaultRelease = context.release;

        context.allocate = LogAllocate;
        context.retain = LogRetain;
        context.release = LogRelease;

        theLogAllocator = CFAllocatorCreate(kCFAllocatorUseContext, &context);
    }

    return theLogAllocator;
}
```

However, it seems that the default allocator (`kCFAllocatorSystemDefault` as far as I can tell) has NULL for context.retain and context.release, so I don't have any original implementations to call. That may be why, when I try the code above, I get the following stack trace:

```
#0  0x357ded12 in CFRetain ()
#1  0x357dcb68 in _CFRuntimeCreateInstance ()
#2  0x303fe35e in CGTypeCreateInstanceWithAllocator ()
#3  0x303fe34c in CGTypeCreateInstance ()
#4  0x304b32f4 in CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider ()
#5  0x000293f4 in MyPDFDocumentCreate ([...]) at [...]
```

XCode doesn't actually tell me why it's halting, but if I try to continue I get:

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x357ded12 in CFRetain ()
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x357ded12 in CFRetain ()
(gdb)
```

However many times I continue, I get the same SIGTRAP. I don't know how to interpret it; the only breakpoint I have set up is a symbolic one on `objc_exception_throw`.

One thing to note is that `LogRetain()` and `LogAllocate()` are each called successfully once (in that order) from `CFAllocatorCreate()`:

```
#0  LogRetain (info=0x1a8000) at [...]
#1  0x358086f2 in CFAllocatorCreate ()
#2  0x00028d58 in MyLogAllocator () at [...] 
#3  0x000293e0 in MyPDFDocumentCreate ([...]) at [...]

#0  LogAllocate (size=104, hint=0, info=0x1a8000) at [...] 
#1  0x3580882e in CFAllocatorCreate ()
#2  0x00028d58 in MyLogAllocator () at [...]
#3  0x000293e0 in MyPDFDocumentCreate ([...]) at [...]
```

And then `LogAllocate()` is again successful from `CFAllocatorAllocate()`:

```
#0  LogAllocate (size=64, hint=1024, info=0x1a8000) at [...] 
#1  0x357dcc06 in CFAllocatorAllocate ()
#2  0x357dcb04 in _CFRuntimeCreateInstance ()
#3  0x303fe35e in CGTypeCreateInstanceWithAllocator ()
#4  0x303fe34c in CGTypeCreateInstance ()
#5  0x304b32f4 in CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider ()
#6  0x000293f4 in MyPDFDocumentCreate ([...]) at [...]
```

before the `_CFRuntimeCreateInstance()` at #2 calls the problematic `CFRetain()` detailed above.

Could somebody please help me to understand what's going on here (especially how the default allocator handles retain and release, and why I'm getting the SIGTRAP); how to fix it; and whether there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

(I figured I might be able to work out how to use DTrace to probe `CFRetain()` and `CFRelease()`, filtered by the `CFTypeID` for `CGPDFDocument`, but I wouldn't know what to probe for deallocation (allocation is not so important to track as I know it's done within `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider()`). Also, I'd prefer to be able to break to the debugger on retain / release / deallocate, which I don't think is possible using DTrace.)

**UPDATE:** Having now read the [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFRuntime.c) for `CFRelease` I realise I misunderstood the purpose of `context.retain` and `context.release` -- they are for retaining and releasing `context.info`. So the entire approach described above is a non-starter. However, perhaps a DTrace/Instruments wizard may still be able to work some magic?!

Comment: Hi, I'm getting little bit confusion to allocate the memory for CFAllocatorRef. I know the two way to create memory using default and NULL but that memory was not enough for my application. Can u pls help me to create some manual memory for my app..!! Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very interesting problem. Since you've gone as deep as investigating filtering DTrace, and you're diving into the `CFRelease` source, then you can look at using gdb breakpoint conditions to choose when to break. To determine if a deallocation is going to occur, just use `CFGetRetainCount()`.

That said, I'm guessing you're pulling your hair out tracking down some over-release crash, right? Things to look at that are probably more useful than reverse-engineering `CFRelease()`:

- [CFZombie](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CFZombie)
- Instruments' Allocations instrument provides full stacks of when objects were retained and released, allocated and destroyed. Turn on the option "Record reference counts."

Comment: It was a leak rather than an over-release, and I ended up writing a minimal nonatomic ObjC wrapper and changing code, but next time I shall use GDB breakpoints or Instruments. Thanks!